# How to add a tooltip to the bootstrap thumbnail and make it invisible again when the user clicks anywhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a thumbnail like follows and i am using twitter bootstrap

```
         <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#profile-image").popover({ 
     html : true,
     content: function() {
       return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
     }
   });
 });
```

```
  <div class="span2 pull-left">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
              <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" id="profile-image" class="thumbnail" rel="popover" data-placement= "bottom" data-trigger="click">
                 <img data-src="holder.js/160x120" src="resources/profile-pics/male/large.jpg" alt="">
               </a>
               <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Edit Profile Picture</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                </ul>
                       </div>
              </div>
              </li>
           </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="well span5">

  </div>

  <div class="well span3 pull-right">

  </div>
```

My requirement is when the user hover over over the image a tool is show.
I tried to use http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers but it's not working. the tool tip only becomes invisible when the user clicks on the link. It would be more good if the tooltip becomes invisible again. ALso is it possible to add a div element to the tooltip element.

I am trying to make something like facebook profile image.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -  `data-trigger="hover"`

Yes you can add `html elements` into popovers.

[Jsfiddle on popover ( onhover property)](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/FLFSc/1/)

```
$(function ()  
{ $("#hover").popover({trigger: 'hover'});  
});
```

Comment: When i use data trigger hover the moment i take my cursor over the tooltip the popover becomes invisible. I am planning to put 5 buttons inside the popover. This is the reason i am using data-trigger: click so the popover dosent become inviible.

Comment: So wat exactly you want to display

Comment: I edited my html. I added my view and i want the facebook view.

Comment: I edited my html. I added my view and i want the facebook view if possible. What i am struggling is when we hover over the popover is visible but the moment i take my cursor over the tooltip the tooltip becomes invisible.:(

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle now

Comment: Looks perfect. Thanks. Could you also add there the functionality that when the user clicks on "Edit profile picture" a drop is attached to the same. Thanks a lot.:)

Comment: Can you please select it as an answer

Comment: @Sahil : Could you help me in this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944122/how-to-hide-everything-inside-a-li-element-and-insert-a-div-dynamically